# How to add a connection string in DNN 8

Tags: .net, web-config, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-8

DNN 8 appears to have an encrypted connection string to access its database:

```
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
  <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
        </KeyInfo>
        <CipherData>
          <CipherValue>MINjgIFInXezSIMnkeV2AoPfb69wdpXKG89QUv2IHlPwwsEg5VZjWWOx+Cf/xXzFhrPQV3QINry5WYq/KCBnsfIHfQHJSzzVtqkXB/OX2/oDSHZc7lRVIExNdHCkmSmyRneZP5hJEN6qm6RTHncJbmPLk7zO2D7om5SyfJ48bzo=</CipherValue>
        </CipherData>
      </EncryptedKey>
    </KeyInfo>
    <CipherData>
      <CipherValue>JRI+aV/tS2D0Xf3bDV2MJIqj6m0csfxF3KzRse4ij/H77NZSlP8BfHlfYk6Iw1jtbE2T2BZc7wjDj7CqFbqqRRUQMQE41XlP9VQQU/uIxR6R7AafCgTiE/iUUlACEvweRPw2y8p+vGF4zpzUS67OGb3tZgA6kUrg0piJLSWJvXvsZ/MFUMZy6OFljKQGKVTnsd94CUKonf0NmpuuSYSVKsbuPxZzQ4H1wg+H4vFkbOUJSjv13J0ioRtFOpPdugtPW/FdDAS+Y4hGfGUrpqXT6604+JuJc53/yAVsXDvzHWQ=</CipherValue>
    </CipherData>
  </EncryptedData>
</connectionStrings>
```

I would like to add another connection string to a separate database that I need to access while developing custom modules.  How do I add an unencrypted connection string or, how do I encrypt the additional connection string and add it to the web.config?

Comment: FYI I don't think DNN encrypts those out of the box, of my hundreds of DNN installs I've never seen it without manually doing it.

Comment: I'd never seen it before either.  But I'd never installed version 8 before.  I'm certain I didn't encrypt it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.  You have to decrypt the connectionString section of the web.config then you can add additional connection strings.  You can re-encrypt if you like after that (or leave it as is).  To decrypt:

Install the .NET SDK on the web server

Call up an elevated command prompt

Enter: aspnet_regiis -pdf "connectionStrings" "path to folder containing web.config"

If all goes well, this will decrypt your connection string

Answer (score 0):

In the web.config file, simply go to the connectionStrings node and add a new record there. Here's a sample (you wouldn't need to add the connectionStrings node, just insert your new record before the ending node.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NewSQLConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=DatabaseUser;Password=DataBasePassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid it isn't that easy.  My configurationstrings are encrypted and you can't just add an unencrypted record to the node.  It throws an error about a malformed web.config if you do so (The section is marked as being protected...).